# Why won't re.search return any matches?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract a specific line beginning with the character '>' from a large document.
[line I am trying to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN7id.png)

Why doesn't this code work to pull out the contents of any line that begins with '>'?

```
import sys
import re

Input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
Output = open(sys.argv[1]+'.summary', 'w')

if re.match('>\s\S+', line): 
    mo2 = re.search('>\s\S+', line) 
    Hit = mo2.group(1)
    print(Hit)
```

Comment: The variable `line` is undefined.

Comment: Also the regex used to create `mo2` does not have any capture groups, so `group(1)` will always be `None`.  You might have meant `group(0)` to get the entire matched text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is lines that begin with ">", there's no need for regular expressions.

```
for line in Input:
    if line[0] == '>':
        print(line, end='', file=Output)
```

Of course, in that case, there's no need for Python.  Just do

```
grep ^>  < infile > outfile
```